# does not display all the overlays, generating from kml file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, kml

I am drawing overlay on map from kml file which i store in my documents directory. i am viewing about 30 to 40 kml file at once with the line color stored itself in the kml. the problem is some of them doesn't display.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    return [kmlParser viewForOverlay:overlay];
}
```

above code is from the reference KMLViewer which can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/kmlviewer/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010046-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_9)

when i write the below code it works perfectly fine but all the generated kml file draws with the black color

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
        MKOverlayPathView *overlayPathView;

        if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
        {
            overlayPathView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon*)overlay];

            overlayPathView.fillColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
            overlayPathView.strokeColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
            overlayPathView.lineWidth = 3;

            return overlayPathView;
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly Appreciable!

Thanks.

Comment: issue has been resolved having problem with boundingMapRect

Answer (score 1):

boundingMapRect might be the culprit please check the zoom level of map as well as its boundingmaprect property